# VB.NET How to reuse/ requery/ reset /clear an existing chart to display new data

Tags: vb.net, charts

I'm trying to reuse my chart but i'm getting the error

> A chart element with the name 'Series1' could not be found in the 'SeriesCollection'.

every time i try to requery. i tried to add this 3 line of codes before calling my function but to no avail, any ideas?

`Chart1.DataSource = Nothing 
 Chart1.Series.Clear()
 Chart1.ChartAreas.Clear()`

My code:

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   'still getting the same error
   'Chart1.DataSource = Nothing
   'Chart1.Series.Clear()
   'Chart1.ChartAreas.Clear()
   GetData()
End Sub

Private Sub GetData()
    If Not cnninventory.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnninventory.Open()
    End If
    Dim d1 As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim d2 As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value
    Dim searchsql1 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from saleshisTBL where HistDate >= #" & String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", d1) & "# and HistDate <= #" & String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", d2) & "# ORDER BY HistDate ", cnninventory)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    searchsql1.Fill(ds, "saleshisTBL")
    Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables("saleshisTBL")
    Dim Series1 As Series = Chart1.Series("Series1")
    Series1.Name = "Sales"
    Chart1.Series(Series1.Name).XValueMember = "ItemSold"
    Chart1.Series(Series1.Name).YValueMembers = "Quantity"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you added "Series1" to the chart in some other part of code ? If yes please show that part of code. If not Chart1.Series.Add("Series1") to be added.

Comment: i tried declaring it as a global variable didn't worked, updated my question to show "Dim Series1 As Series = Chart1.Series("Series1")"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below, it should work for you as well

```
Private Sub GetData()
    If Not cnninventory.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnninventory.Open()
    End If
    Dim d1 As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim d2 As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value
    Dim searchsql1 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from saleshisTBL where HistDate >= #" & String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", d1) & "# and HistDate <= #" & String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", d2) & "# ORDER BY HistDate ", cnninventory)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    searchsql1.Fill(ds, "saleshisTBL")
    Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables("saleshisTBL")

    Chart1.Series.Clear()
    Dim Series1 As New DataVisualization.Charting.Series
    With Series1
        .Name = "Sales"
        .ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar
        .XValueMember = "ItemSold"
        .YValueMembers = "Quantity"
    End With
    Chart1.Series.Add(Series1)
    Chart1.Invalidate()

End Sub
```